# Submit forms in HTML using textarea

Tags: php, html

is there any way i can submit a form without creating submit button, but using only type="text"? whenever i type every variable in the text area it submits.

I'm trying to create a live search using html and php mysql.

Comment: use ajax and auto suggestion

Comment: you can't have live search just with php, try javascript

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? For example googling "php live search"? I'm sure there will be dozens of answers to your question.

Comment: Are you talking about a `<textarea>`, or an `<input type="text" />`? Your question is confusing... Please also share whatever code you've already tried.

Comment: im just submitting it in the same file. i just want to change the displayed table from the database using if statements and rejex

Answer (score 1):

use `onBlur` event on `textarea` element and submit your form using java script like this

```
<form id="testform">
<textarea onblur="submitForm()"></textare>
</form>

<script>
function submitForm(){
document.getElementById("testform").submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a live search you're going to need to investigate AJAX (aka XHR).  Submitting a form every time somebody changes the value of a textbox is a really bad way of doing it.

However if you *really* wanted to then you're going to have to attach an event listener to the textbox, listening for a keypress or keyup event.

What (if any) Framework are you using.

Comment: im just submitting it in the same page btw. every time it submits the value that is retrieved from the database is constantly changing.

Comment: You'd still be better off using an AJAX request.  To do a live lookup you need to do a query every time the text changes, by doing a submit you have to retrieve the whole page from the browser every single time.  However in a similar vein to above you could do this:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H9bUk/

This should work to submit everytime a key is pressed